# Return row number within user-defined range rather than absolute row number

Tags: vba, excel

I have the range `rngData` and array `aCopyrows() [int]`.

The following loop is used to populate the array:

```
For Each c In rngData

    If c.Value = "Search term 1" Then
        aCopyrow(1) = c.Row
    ElseIf c.Value = "Search term 2" Then
        aCopyrow(2) = c.Row
    ElseIf c.Value = "Search term 3" Then
        aCopyrow(3) = c.Row
    End If

Next c
```

I want the array to store the row numbers corresponding to `rngData`, or in other words: if a match is found in the first row of `rngData`, the integer 1 is stored in `aCopyrow`. However, using this method stores the global row number of that particular cell.

Any help appreciated!

`rngData.c.Row` just gives me an error (method not supported).

Comment: Is there a possibility that `rngData` can have multiple `Search term 1` or `Search term 2` or `Search term 3`?

Comment: No, the search terms are company names and can only occur once.

Comment: One last Question. Are these values in a single Row/Column. i.e is `rngData` like `I13:M13` or `B1:B100`?

Comment: Please note, you should mark your questions as solved if you get a suitable answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
aCopyrow(1) = c.Row  - rngData.Cells(1,1).Row + 1
```

and if there are more than 3 Ifs, you could iterate like this to make the code more compact:

```
Dim i as Long

For Each c In rngData

    For i = 1 To 3
        If c.Value = "Search term " & i Then
            aCopyrow(i) = c.Row  - rngData.Cells(1,1).Row + 1
        End If
    Next i

Next c
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but there will only be three search terms. Your solution is kind of what I'm doing now, although I find it a bit clumsy. But maybe it's the only way, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of the data, it will be a lot faster:

```
Dim vArray As Variant

vArray = rngData.Value

For lRow = 1 To UBound(vArray, 1)
    For lCol = 1 To UBound(vArray, 2)
        If vArray(lRow, lCol) = "Search term 1" Then
            aCopyrow(1) = lRow
        ElseIf vArray(lRow, lCol) = "Search term 2" Then
            aCopyrow(2) = lRow
        ElseIf vArray(lRow, lCol) = "Search term 3" Then
            aCopyrow(3) = lRow
        End If
    Next lCol
Next lRow
```